# Can I use SQL Server Developer edition (free license) for Non-Production environmen that is used for training

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Client uses SQL Server 2012 Dev environment for Training, is this regarded as a Prod or Non-Prod activity? Please point me in the direction of a Microsoft documentation for this scenario. Thank you.

Comment: The license is installed with the product eg: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\License Terms

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because licensing questions are off topic here. Contact MS directly for clarification on legal usage scenarios.